# Automatically call function after changing element of list using __getitem__

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a project with a class "ListObject" containing a list and a string attribute "_quality" explaining the list content. The string attribute is calculated through a private method of the class called "_update_quality(self)". The list is populated with instances of an object "Element": it has an int attribute "_value" that can be changed through the public method "add(self, value)" that takes an int value and adds it to _value.

ListObject has a public method "change_item(self, index, value)" that let the user add an int value to the Element instance at the given index.

You can read and run the code below to see how it works.

```
class Element:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = 0
    
    def add(self, value):
        self._value += value
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._value)
    
    
class ListObject:
    def __init__(self):
        self._list = list()
        self._quality = str()
        
        self._list.append(Element())
        self._list.append(Element())
        self._list.append(Element())
        
        self._update_quality()
    
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._list[item]
    
    def _update_quality(self):
        self._quality = str()
        
        for item in self._list:
            self._quality += str(item)
        
    def change_item(self, index, value):
        self._list[index].add(value)
        self._update_quality()
    
    @property
    def quality(self):
        return self._quality
    

o = ListObject()
print(o.quality)
o.change_item(0, 5)
print(o.quality)
```

What I'd like to implement is a **getitem** method inside ListObject that works like "change_item". The method should automatically call "_update_quality". This should be the code:

```
o = ListObject()
print(o.quality)
o[0].add(5)
print(o.quality)
```

and it should generate the same output as the previous one.

Does anyone knows how I can achieve this?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? It would work *exactly* like the method you already have. Or you could just clal `change_item` in it.

Comment: The problem is that I'd like to directly access to Element methods (like `o[0].add(5)`, I'm directly calling `add` method of the 0 Element) and I can do that only after the `return` of `__getitem__`. So I can't call `_update_quality` inside `__getitem__` (before return has no sense, nothing still changed), and I can't call `change_item` inside `__getitem__` because I have "index" argument but not "value". If you run the last 4 lines of code you can see that the output is different, the 2° print is equal to the first but it should change.